# Hesronot Hashas English translation

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

I am looking for an English translation of the Hesronot Hashas.  Anyone aware of an honest and complete translation of this document?  Also what does Hesronot Hashas mean?

Comment: Hesronot Hashas - means omissions from the original text of the Talmud, usually by censorship. I am not sure there was only a single book with this title.

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea if anyone has ever made a copy of it in English?  I have a copy in Hebrew from Tel Aviv, but I do not read Hebrew.  If there is more than one, I was not aware of that.  I just have one.

Comment: Hopefully there isn't and if it does exist hopefully someone with a tag name like yours doesn't find it.